# Android studio - Different device is using the same layout, but everything looks good only on one of them

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

- I have 4 sets of layout xml and corresponding drawbles, including hdpi, tvdpi, xhdpi, and xxhdpi
- I have 2 phones to test the app on, one is a virtual Nexus 5x, another one is a physical Galaxy Note 4
- The xml layout works out perfectly on the Nexus 5x, but since (I assume) Note 4 has a smaller resolution / different ratio, the content is overlapping a little bit on it.

This app is very different than regular ones since it has a lot of image views in a relative layout arranged in a specific pattern. Problem is that the system is using xxhdpi resource and layout on both of the device. How do I fix it in a situation like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image]I faced the same problem few days ago.Use dimen.xml which is lacated under values folder.Make folder like values-sw600dp and make dimen.xml under this. Define all the relations in there and call it using @dimen/....
Android automatically will choose best match for your device.